# Spark RDD: Get row number

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

How do I get the row number out of an RDD that I'm currently processing:

```
val rdd2 = rdd1
  .filter(row => {
          // get row number
      }
      true
  })
```

Comment: Does your RDD contain objects with a "row" attribute, or are you asking how to get the "position" within the RDD? the latter only makes sense if the RDD has an ordering and it generally does not -- only does if you sort.

Answer (score 4):

```
val rdd2 = rdd1.zipWithIndex.filter{ 
    case (row, index) => {
      // row number is index. (but is not fixed, unless RDD is sorted)
}
```